# Create HTML List From Array

Tags: php, html

I wish to create a list from an array, but not just any array, no, that would be too simple. The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [content] => Lost my heart and a leg in Australia
            [path] => {1}
            [depth] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [content] => I left my heart in sandcrabs bistro
            [path] => {1,5}
            [depth] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [content] => I left my heart in San Francisco
            [path] => {1,5,7}
            [depth] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [content] => That is the worst joke ever.
            [path] => {1,5,7,9}
            [depth] => 4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [content] => Worst joke evar.
            [path] => {1,5,7,10}
            [depth] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [content] => What happened to mudcrab?
            [path] => {1,5,8}
            [depth] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [content] => I am the tinman, and have no heart
            [path] => {1,6}
            [depth] => 2
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [content] => Even on land there are loan sharks
            [path] => {4}
            [depth] => 1
        )

)
```

And The HTML should look like this:

```
<ul><!-- level 1 -->
    <li>Lost my heart and a leg in Australia</li>
    <li>
        <ul><!-- level 2 -->
            <li>I left my heart in sandcrabs bistro</li>
            <li>
                <ul><!-- level 3 -->
                    <li>I left my heart in San Francisco</li>
                    <li>
                        <ul><!-- level 4 -->
                            <li>That is the worst joke ever</li>
                            <li>Worst joke evar</li>
                        </ul><!-- end level 4 -->
                    <li>What happened to mudcrab?</li>
                </ul><!-- end level 3 -->
            <li>I am the tinman, and have no heart</li>
        </ul><!-- end level 2 -->
    <li>Even on land there are loan sharks</li>
</ul><!-- end level 1 -->
```

Any suggestions on how to get the levels/depths correct greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post array code.

Comment: The array is derived from a recursive CTE in PgSQL using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC.

Comment: Justinas: I have tried looping, and building a tree, that I could then loop over to create the html, but I get stuck with build an array of arrays which represents the html tree.